# Can't install curl on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, curl

I can't install curl on Ubuntu 14.04.

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

Error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 curl : Depends: libcurl3 (= 7.34.0-1ubuntu1) but 7.35.0-1ubuntu2.5 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get update` and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run apt-get update. If this doesn't work, the repositories in your /etc/apt/sources.list might be wrong

Comment: curl (7.35.0-1ubuntu2.5) would be provided by either trusty-security or trusty-updates. ( generally smart to have both enabled.

Comment: Thanks! Change repositories to another server helped me solve it.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I add this line in `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

put these two lines:

```
deb http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main
deb-src http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main
```

after that

```
apt-get update
```

And after this I can install `curl`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem installing aptitude.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

And later trying to install curl with aptitude:

```
sudo aptitude install grive-tools
```

After that it prompts with a solution to unmet dependencies (maybe the ones that were faulty in the first place).